# Kann "heute" ein Substantiv sein?

Tags: noun

Ich wollte sagen: "Heute ist ein Beispiel für..." (This day/Today is an example for [...])

Ist das korrekt? Oder ist nur "Dieser Tag ist einen Beispiel für..." möglich?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Es klingt nicht direkt falsch und trotzdem ist der Satz zumindest merkwürdig. Die Verwendung von *Heute* als Substantiv ist alles andere als idiomatisch.
Der Duden definiert das Substantiv [Heute](http://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/Heute) als "die Gegenwart". Aber selbst hier würde man eher zum Adverb (im Sinne von *gegenwärtig*) greifen. Ich habe zumindest keine Treffer zum Substantiv im Wortschatz-Portal oder in DWDS gefunden.

Prinzipiell kann man jegliche Adverbien substantivieren, der Duden zeigt das auch unter anderem [am Beispiel von *heute*](http://www.duden.de/sprachwissen/sprachratgeber/substantivierte-adverbien-praepositionen-u-a) (wobei hier wieder Bezug auf Gegenwart genommen wird). Selbiges Beispiel wird auch im Wikipedia-Artikel zu [Substantivierung](http://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Substantivierung) aufgezählt.

Lange Rede, kurzer Sinn:
In deinem Beispiel schlage ich die Verwendung des Adjektivs *heutig* vor:

> Der heutige Tag ist ein Beispiel für …

Answer (score 5):

Also zumindest ein Beispiel fällt mir ein, wo ein substantiviertes "Heute" durchaus üblich ist, nämlich bei der Phrase

> ...im Hier und Heute...

als Synonym für

> ...im Hier und Jetzt...

Vgl. auch die Übersetzung in [dict.cc](http://www.dict.cc/?s=im%20hier%20und%20heute). Bspw.

> Die meisten Menschen haben verlernt, im Hier und Heute zu leben.

Ansonsten schließe ich mich @Em1 mit seinem Übersetzungsvorschlag an.

Answer (score 1):

Es ist persönliche Geschmackssache, ob man das substantivierte Heute oder eine Umschreibung benutzen möchte, beides ist richtig und wird auch verstanden:

[image]

<sup>[Google ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=das%20Heute%2Cder%20heutige%20Tag%2Cdas%20heute&year_start=1800&year_end=2008&corpus=20&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cdas%20Heute%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cder%20heutige%20Tag%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cdas%20heute%3B%2Cc0)</sup>

Innerhalb eines Satzes erklärt sich allein schon durch die Großschreibung die Verwendung als Substantiv. Einzig am Satzanfang ist dies nicht eindeutig. Man könnte Klarheit schaffen, indem man einen Artikel einfügt:

> Das Heute ist ein Beispiel dafür ...

Comment: Ja, soweit richtig und eine nette Statistik :-) 
Ich glaube nur, dass sich user85190 auf exakt den heutigen Tag beziehen will und nicht nur auf die vage "Gegenwart". Meiner Meinung nach kommt diese Bedeutung in *Das Heute ist ein Beispiel dafür* nicht heraus.

Comment: Wir wissen eigentlich nicht so recht, welchen Kontext die Frage meint... es könnte auch *"Das Heute ist ein Beispiel dafür, wie Computer die Welt beherrschen."* sein.

Comment: @Em1: "Dieser Tag" könnte natürlich aber auch völlig falsch sein, je nach Kontext... Nachdem der Kontext fehlt kann man die Frage auch als eine allgemeine Frage, dahingehend ob "heute" auch ein Nomen sein kann, verstehen. Es hängt schon vom Kontext ab, ob ein substantiviertes "Heute" unidiomatisch ist oder nicht... man kann es jedenfalls nicht pauschal ablehnen.

Comment: Danke für die Erklärungen, ich verstehe jetzt das ein bisschen besser!

Answer (score 1):

If you use `heute` like in

> Heute ist ein Beispiel für einen miesen Tag.

then you're not using the word as an adverb. If you were, you could leave it out, and still have an at least halfway senseful sentence with nearly the same meaning. But that is not the case. Instead, you're using the wor as a noun (a short form of `der heutige Tag`). That way, it functions as an obligatory nominative object to `sein` in its meaning of equality.

If you use `heute` like in

> Heute ist ein guter Tag zum Sterben.

then you're using it as an adverb: *The good day to die happens during the present day.* You can leave it and get a senseful sentence with nearly the same meaning:

> Ein guter Tag zum Sterben ist.

which isn't idiomatic at all, but grammatically correct. (The idiomatic expression would be `Es ist ein guter Tag zum Sterben.`)

Comment: "Ein guter Tag zum Sterben ist" is not grammatically correct. "Ist" (a linking verb) always requires a complement.

Comment: @Em1 „Ich denke, also bin ich.“ You want to denounce this beautiful sentence as grammatically incorrect? `ist` is not necessarily linking. But the non-linking version is in most cases of no use, consequently not used very much and as such unidiomatic, but not grammatically incorrect.